# Multiple IPs on single server - Specify which is used to connect (MS server 2008 / DNS)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, ip

I have a Windows 2008 server with multiple IPs that is acting as DNS server. I have set the DNS server up to only accept connections on a single of these IPs.
The DNS is serving as secondary DNS and when it connects to the primary DNS server it is not connecting with this particular IP address, but one of the other IPs.
Is there a way in which I can make sure the server connects using the correct IP?

Answer (score 0):

Windows OS have a Route Table, used to choose an interface for external communication. In a Cmd prompt, **route print** will show said table, with both active and persistent routes along with a interface list.

Persistent routes are manual entries that won't get deleted even if the interface went down.

===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric

As to enforce a certain destination to use a certain interface, i would recommend a persistent route,

Syntax:

**route** ADD  157.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0  157.55.80.1 METRIC 3 IF 2

**route** command *destination* **MASK** *network mask* *gateway* **Metric** *metic number* **IF** *interface number*

If IF is not given, it tries to find the best interface for a given
gateway.

The interface number is displayed in the interface list shown earlier.

Fernando Ramos